# AngularJS: cannot access property of JSON Object: get undefined error

Tags: json, angularjs, parsing

Using AngularJS I have a radio group returning an object to a function `selectItem(selectedItem)` in a controller.

The function duly receives the object and a `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedItem)` shows the object is being returned: selectedItem is

```
"{\"__metadata\":
   {\"id\":\"4\",
    \"descriptives\":{},
    \"dates\":{}},
    \"project_id\":4,
    \"projectName\":\"Fonte Verde\",
    \"projectDescription\":\"PGM Ni Cu deposit near Argent in Mpumalanga that is capable of being mined open cast.\",
    \"lkcountry_id\":160,
    \"lkmineralsgroup_id\":9,
    \"person_id\":3,
    \"uniqueNumber\":\"22230\"}"
```

This response (ie with the metadata, and the escape slashes) is in the same format as returned in other situations (e.g. an edit form and when returned to the RESTful API is duly saved).

But when I try to access a value in the returned JSON object using:
`console.log('selectedItem.project_id is ' + selectedItem.project_id)`;
I get the following:

```
selectedItem.project_id is undefined
```

Any ideas? It makes no sense to me though I confess I am a newbit to all of this.

Comment: Can you give us the value of `console.log(selectedItem)` right before your `console.log('selectedItem.project_id is ' + selectedItem.project_id);` line.

Comment: Sounds like `selectedItem` is a string, not an object. Parse it with `JSON.parse()`. e.g. `JSON.parse(selectedItem).project_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/h74ors85/1/)

You need to use JSON.parse before access the property